# Variable assigned to axios response data breaks app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have the following code:

```
 const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };

 const data = JSON.stringify({ postId });

 console.log('sending request'); // prints

 const response = await axios.post(
 `http://${GATEWAY}:5000/api/posts/single`,
 data,
 config
 );

 console.log("response received"); // never reached
```

But when I change

```
 const response = await axios.post(...
```

to

```
 const res = await axios.post(...
```

or literally any other word for that matter, `response received` is printed and the app doesn't crash. Does anyone have any insight into this? Memory leak?

Comment: put the code inside a try...catch statement and console.log the error

Comment: Is there any errors? Or the app just freezes and close?

Comment: Do you maybe have `response` declared somewhere in the function before you are trying to assign the axios response to it? like in the arguments etc.

Comment: app just freezes and closes. and no errors are thrown. i've kind of figured it out though, it was a redux issue. fixed it by just taking another approach to updating my app level state. I had a `dispatch({type: SET_DATA, payload: response.data`. Commenting that out makes the app work regardless of how I call the axios response object